# execl doesn't work in a while(1) loop, server side; C script

Tags: c, sockets, udp, broadcast, os.execl

I have a problem with a little C script which should run as a server and launch a popup for every message arriving.
The [execl](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execl.htm) syntax is correct because if I try a little script with

```
main() { execl(...); }
```

it works.

When I put it in a while(1) loop it doesn't work. Everything else is working, like `printf` or string operation, but not the `execl`. Even if I fork it doesn't work.
How can I make it work?

And I've tried with the `fork()`, but it doesn't work either.

Here's the complete server C code.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFLEN 512
#define PORT 9930

void diep(char *s) {
     perror(s);
     exit(1);
}

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
    int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other), broadcastPermission;
    char buf[100], zeni[BUFLEN];

    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
       diep("socket");

    broadcastPermission = 1;
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void *) &broadcastPermission, sizeof(broadcastPermission)) < 0)
        diep("setsockopt() failed");

    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind(s, &si_me, sizeof(si_me))==-1)
       diep("bind");

    while (1) {
        if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, &slen)==-1) diep("recvfrom()");
        //printf("Received packet from %s:%d\nData: %s\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port), buf);

 strcpy(zeni, "");
 strcat(zeni, "zenity --warning --title Hack!! --text ");
 strcat(zeni, buf);
 printf("cmd: %s\n", zeni);
 //system (zeni);
 execl("/usr/bin/zenity", "/usr/bin/zenity", "--warning", "--title", "Warn!", "--text", buf, (char *) NULL);
    }

    close(s);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a stack overflow in your call to `recvfrom`.

```
recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, &slen)
```

I believe you mixed the 2 buffers. You're using `buf`, which has size 100, but telling its size is BUFLEN, which is 512. Whenever someone sends more than 100 bytes, it's very likely your program is going to crash.

Besides that, it's possible that the `recvfrom` is not returning because it isn't receiving anything. Is your `printf` being executed?

---

UPDATE: as pointed by @Daniel and @Dale, `execl` won't return unless an error occurs. Quoting from the man-page:

> The exec family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

As alternative, you can use `system`.

Comment: True for the overflow error, my bad.
But the recvfrom works great because the incoming message is very short; and yes, the printf works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

@jweyrich has already pointed out some problems with your use of `recvfrom`, however there is a more fundamental problem.  The code

```
while (1) {
    recvfrom(...);
    execl(...);
}
```

will only ever execute at most once.  This because the `exec` family of system calls (including `execl`) replace the the program currently executing with the one given in the call to `execl`.  In effect, `execl` never returns, except with an error.

To create a new child process in unix, you must first call `fork`, which clones the existing process, and then within the child call `execl` (or some related system call) to replace child process with the program you actually want to run.  Doing this correctly manually is somewhat tricky, so the `system` function wraps this up for you, however it has it's own drawbacks.

Comment: Very valid point. Since he put it in a loop, I should've supposed he plans to run more than once. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Please read exec(3) man page.

In your case execl system call will replace current processes image with the image of 
/usr/bin/zenity".

You have two solutions: use system(3) as you tried there or do a fork and inside the child run execlp.